# Find rectangle vertices from 4 points located at rectangle faces.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction, rectangles

If I have 4 points: $P_a$, $P_b$, $P_c$, and $P_d$. And each of these points lies on a different face of a rectangle, how do I find the vertices ($V_1$,$V_2$,$V_3$, and $V_4$) of this rectangle?

[Rectangle with vertices v1,v2,v3 and v4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wxRK.png)

[image: Graphical setup of the problem]

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many such rectangles.

Let $La$ be any line through $Pa$. Let $Lb$ and $Ld$ be the lines through $Pb$ and $Pd$ perpendicular to $La$. Then let $Lc$ be the line through $Pc$ parallel to $La$. Those four lines will intersect at the vertices of a rectangle of the kind you seek, as long as the points $Px$ are interior to the segments defined by the vertices. That will be true for a whole range of lines $L$.

You can see that in the picture in the question: just imagine rotating the edge through $Pa$ a little bit and adjusting the other edges so as to keep the right angles.

There will be cases when there is no rectangle - one of the four points might be inside the triangle formed by the other three. There will be edge cases - what if three of the points are collinear?

Comment: +1 I have checked this in geogebra and it is true.

Comment: https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/eafbnbek is a GeoGebra file showing this.  You can move corner $E$ anywhere on the semicircle joining $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Nice. For some of the positions $E$ on the semicircle point $D$ is outside the rectangle.

Comment: @EthanBolker True.  I didn't mean to imply that that was a complete characterization of the loci of corners, especially as you note that you can drag the first four points around to make the problem unsolvable.  But it shows where the problem can be solved.

Comment: Thank you! I guess that if I have 5 points, with 2 of them belonging to the same face, I'm able to uniquely determine the rectangle, correct?

Comment: @RicardoAchilles Yes, if you specify which pair that is, and which of the other three is on the edge opposite. You will still have to worry about impossible cases, unless you know from conbext that there is a rectangle that works. Then there will be just one, and the answer tells you how to find its vertices.